# Tensorflow - How is the graph executed?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to get an output of an activation function as the weights change. When the weights change I expect the activation function to change as well.

I am simply changing the weights before the activation and I get a change in the value of the activation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))
def dummy(x):
    weights['h0'] = tf.assign(weights['h0'], tf.add(weights['h0'], 0.1))
    res = tf.add(weights['h0'], x)
    res = sigmoid(res)
    return res

# build computational graph
a = tf.placeholder('float', None)
d = dummy(a)
weights = {
    'h0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}
# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        print (sess.run(d, feed_dict={a: [2]}))
# close session
sess.close()
```

But when I try to change the weights after the activation such as in backprop, I get the same activation every time. Can anyone explain to me what is happening and what I can do to get the activation to change after every iteration?

```
import tensorflow as tf
def sigmoid(x, derivative = False):
    if derivative == True:
        return (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))) * (1.0 - (1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))))
    return 1.0/(1+tf.exp(-x))
def dummy(x):
    res = tf.add(weights['h0'], x)
    res = sigmoid(res)
    weights['h0'] = tf.assign(weights['h0'], tf.add(weights['h0'], 0.1))
    return res

# build computational graph
a = tf.placeholder('float', None)
d = dummy(a)
weights = {
    'h0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}
# initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        print (sess.run(d, feed_dict={a: [2]}))
# close session
sess.close()
```

EDIT:

It seems like it is not running the entire graph? I can do this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        sess.run(weights['h0'])
        print (sess.run(d, feed_dict={a: [2]}))
```

Where I run the weights and it gives me different values. Is that correct?

Comment: Your edit is correct, In your original call `sess.run(d, ...`)  will prune the overall graph to a subgraph that doesn't involve the weight update. So you need to call  it explicitly using `sess.run(weights['h0'])` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
    print (sess.run(d, feed_dict={a: [2]}))
```

You need to call `sess.run()` and pass in a training operation, which is usually an optimizer's `minimize()` function.

Below are some example usages.

From the super-simple [Tensorflow MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py):

```py
  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
  ...

  for _ in range(1000):
      ...
      sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

From a [TensorFlow multi-layer NN example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py):

```py
  cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(\
                      logits=pred, labels=y))
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
  ...

  for i in range(total_batch):
      ...
      _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

The general pattern is:

1. Define cost function J.
2. Add the cost variable J to an optimizer
3. Call `sess.run()` with the optimizer variable as an argument.

If you want to write your own optimizer, then you'll need to take a different approach. Writing your own cost function is typical, but writing your own optimizer is not. You should look at the code for [AdamOptimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py) or [GradientDescentOptimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py) for insight.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? While I understand sess.run should be running the graph. In the example why does it not execute the update?

Comment: Thanks, I have seen these tutorials and they all are using builtin optimizers and cost functions. I would like to use my own optimizer and cost function. I.E I want to optimize the weights using my own function. Is it possible to do this? If so how would I implement the SGD optimizer without relying on the TF function?

Comment: @Kevin: Ok, you should have said that at the start. Writing your own cost function is typical, but writing your own optimizer is not. You should look at the code for `AdamOptimizer` or `GradientDescentOptimizer` for insight.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into how optimizers work. Apparently they can go through the graph and look at the trainable weights, and calculate the gradients from these weights following the graph in reverse. Interesting stuff. What piqued my interest is how it handles the batch inputs. even if it calculates the gradients in reverse it doesn't explain how it handles the batch of inputs. maybe an internal loop going through each sample then calculating the gradient for that sample till the batch is done? I will look into it thanks!

Comment: Just make the last comment part of your answer and I will accept it as the answer

Comment: @Kevin: I added some final comments to my answer.